# why updated lifecycle vue.js running after unmount lifecycle?

Tags: vue.js

I try a lifecycle of vue js, when I unmounted, the updated work after that. Anyone know why it happened ?
here's the code for unmount

```
       <script>
export default {
  name:'HelloWorld',
  unmounted()
  {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    alert("Unmounted")
  }
}
</script>
```

and here's is the code for updated

```
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data(){
    return{
      show:true,
      counter:0
    }
  },

  updated(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    alert("Updated");
  }
}
</script>

<template>
<div v-if="show">
  <HelloWorld />
  <button v-on:click="counter=counter+=1">Update is {{ counter }}</button>
  <button v-on:click="show=false">Toggle</button>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: There may be more specific explanations that are based on framework source code, but basically, it works the way you saw it. If it's important, take that into account. Notice that https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#lifecycle-diagram doesn't specify the exact relation between these hooks, not to mention that the one is in a child and another is in a parent

Comment: Alright, I'll try to learn about lifecycle again